# Web api routing, URL not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to create my own Web-Api for a cryptocurrency tracker I am making.

I want to get the values from a db. The technology here is MVC5.

I have a db that contains my wallet value with a time/date attached to it, I then have an api method here:

```
namespace Crytocurrency_Web___Main.Controllers
{
[RoutePrefix("WalletValue")]
public class WalletValueController : ApiController
{
    readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

    [Route("GetAllValues")]
    [HttpGet]
    public List<WalletValue> GetAllValues()
    {
        return dbContext.Wallet.ToList();
    }
  }
}
```

but when I go to the address 
    localhost:51833/WalletValue/GetAllValues  I get the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its 
dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /WalletValue/GetAllValues
```

Here is the route config file too:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

here is document breakdown of where the controller is stored

Solution -> Controllers -> WalletValueController

Scaffolded WebAPi:

```
  public class WalletValuesController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: api/WalletValues
    public IQueryable<WalletValue> GetWallet()
    {
        return db.Wallet;
    }

    // GET: api/WalletValues/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(WalletValue))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetWalletValue(int id)
    {
        WalletValue walletValue = db.Wallet.Find(id);
        if (walletValue == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(walletValue);
    }

    // PUT: api/WalletValues/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutWalletValue(int id, WalletValue walletValue)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != walletValue.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(walletValue).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!WalletValueExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/WalletValues
    [ResponseType(typeof(WalletValue))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostWalletValue(WalletValue walletValue)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Wallet.Add(walletValue);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = walletValue.Id }, walletValue);
    }

    // DELETE: api/WalletValues/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(WalletValue))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteWalletValue(int id)
    {
        WalletValue walletValue = db.Wallet.Find(id);
        if (walletValue == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Wallet.Remove(walletValue);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(walletValue);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool WalletValueExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Wallet.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
```

Comment: I normally put the routes in the HttpGet/Post attribute - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing for more info. There may be some mileage in making a new small MVC project and see how VS configures the routes by default, checking it all works/your IIS isn't missing any components etc

Comment: Your route is exposed in the comment you need to prefix with api/walletvalues

Answer (score 3):

Your `Route` attribute isn't being used. You have to enable attribute routing for Web API with this (in WebApiConfig.cs):

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

You can also add this to enable attribute routing for your non-API controllers (in your `RegisterRoutes` method):

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Once you do that, you can remove the `route.MapRoute` line if you want.

That should make it work as you have it.

But note that you can put `[RoutePrefix("WalletValue")]` on `WalletValueController`, then you just need to put `[Route("GetAllValues")]` on your action. That saves you from having to put `WalletValue/` on every action.

Comment: I've now added the MapMvcAttributeRoutes() but it still isn't working :(

Comment: Do you have a `RoutePrefix` on your controller?

Comment: See editted question, added what you said and it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Sorry, I read the documentation a little closer. Turns out `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` only works for non-API controllers. For API controllers, you need `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` in your WebApiConfig.cs. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I believe I dont have a WebApiConfig file since I didn't chose the webapi template when I first started. Do you know an easy way to set the project up as one or will i have to start again?

Comment: You don't need to start again. Look at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api

Comment: i even scaffolding a WebApi controller using my Coins Model, going to the first call "api/WalletValue" still doesn't work, check edit.

Comment: Partway down, there's an example of what the `WebApiConfig` class should look like. Then you add `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` to your `Application_Start` in your `Global.asax.cs`.

Comment: Perfect, ill look now :)

Comment: Just figured it out. I'm using Hangfire which also uses GlobalConfiguration therefore it was ambiguous